# Check if a connection is in a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting a `SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions.` exception and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407320/strange-sql2005-problem-sqlconnection-does-not-support-parallel-transactions/432165#432165) mentions its when a connection tries to open two transactions. This is exactly what i am doing. I thought nested transactions were ok (i was using sqlite for the prototype).

How do i check if the connection is already in a transaction? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Database File.

Comment: Does the transaction span multiple databases on the one server?

Comment: .NET and no. Its just a connection with a nested transaction. The nested is required and the outer is there for performance reasons (1 vs 25 transaction).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some searching, I found this other [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606995/how-to-implement-nested-sql-transactions-with-ado-net/2607053#2607053).  It turns out that you cannot nest transactions in ADO.NET.  When you try, you probably end up starting two unrelated transactions, which gives the parallel transactions error.

To see if a connection is currently in a transaction, you could:

```
var com = yourConnection.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = "select @@TRANCOUNT";
var trancount = com.ExecuteScalar();
```

This returns the number of nested transactions.

Note that you can nest transactions manually, without using the SqlTransaction object.  For example:

```
var com = yourConnection.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = "BEGIN TRANSACTION";
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
com.CommandText = "BEGIN TRANSACTION";
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable (name) values ('Joe');";
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
com.CommandText = "COMMIT TRANSACTION";
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
com.CommandText = "ROlLBACK TRANSACTION";
com.ExecuteNonQuery();

com.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable";
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} rows.", com.ExecuteScalar());
```

This prints `0`, because the nested transaction was aborted entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this from multiple threads? If so, then asking won't help because between the time you ask and the time you begin a new transaction, some other thread could have begun its own transaction. You will want to use a connection pool to avoid this sort of race condition.

Comment: Each thread has its own connection. I call a function which begins a transaction then in a loop i call another function which also begins a transaction. The subfunction is called all the time and almost everywhere. The first one not so much.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Then you have two general approaches: (1) create and maintain multiple connections per thread, or (2) use a connection pool. Connection pools are a good thing.

Comment: 1) IS already being done and i am unsure what 2 is but looking it up it looks like i am doing that too. I need a way for my nested transaction (made on purpose) to not bother beginning another. I use the subfunc all the time and it needs a transaction. The one above it does not but performance (sqlite) was better with a transaction there. Thus why i purposely have one connection with two/nested transactions

Comment: @acidzombie24: If your program is constructed such that you know when you already have a transaction open and don't need to open another one in the subfunction, then just pass a flag to the subfunction that means "don't open a transaction this time".

Comment: Greg: I was thinking thats what i need to do but was hoping i wouldnt need to do it. (I like how sqlite has that built in). I guess if thats what i need to do i'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a transaction is already open by checking if `cmd.Transaction` is `null`.

Then wrap your code accordingly so if a transaction is already open, then the calling function owns that transaction and will commit it / roll it back appropriately.

```cs
//begin transaction unless one was already started
bool newTransaction = cmd.Transaction == null;
if (newTransaction) cmd.Transaction = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();

try {
    // do Stuff Here
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // commit if it's our to commit
    if (newTransaction) cmd.Transaction.Commit();

} catch (SqlException ex) {
    if (newTransaction && cmd.Transaction != null) cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

Then the parent function can pass in a command and optionally choose to begin it's own transactional block, or if not, one will be created and commited by the called function.